# Trouble with Array within Object pasting as props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am not sure if this is a react issue or a javascript issue.
I have data setup in my state that are objects that contain arrays of objects.
These arrays of objects don't come down properly.
I am attempting to pass the whole array of objects into a sub component as a prop and then iterate over that array to render out each object.  No matter what I do I can't seem to access the array properly.

I hope this is the best way to give you all of my details.

Here is a portion of my state (I only opened one of the groups)

```
    context.js:72 
    (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {id: "5c0fd8da9af84012ee8b5edf", title: "Test", groups: Array(1)}
    1:
    groups: Array(4)
    0: {id: "5c2fdff78b3f6295dce3f63d", title: "Group #1", commands: Array(0)}
    1: {id: "5c2fdffc8b3f6295dce3f63e", title: "Group #2", commands: Array(0)}
    2: {id: "5c2fdfff8b3f6295dce3f63f", title: "Group #3", commands: Array(0)}
    3: {id: "5c2fe0028b3f6295dce3f640", title: "Group #4", commands: Array(0)}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
    id: "5c10307e0ba810224f988e4c"
    title: "Test 2"
    __proto__: Object
    2: {id: "5c2fb6930fb58e8ce67977cc", title: "Next Silo Test", groups: Array(3)}
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Now I want to access the groups array of the silo.  I have backed all the way to the root of my app and still have this problem so it's beyond the prop not passing right.
if I console log the silo and the group items this is the results

```
    silo 
    {id: "5c10307e0ba810224f988e4c", title: 
    "Test 2", groups:                 Array(0)}groups: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: "5c2fdff78b3f6295dce3f63d",                         
    title: "Group #1", commands: Array(0)}1: {id: "5c2fdffc8b3f6295dce3f63e", title: "Group #2", commands: Array(0)}
    2: {id: "5c2fdfff8b3f6295dce3f63f", title: "Group #3", commands: Array(0)}
    3: {id: "5c2fe0028b3f6295dce3f640", title: "Group #4", commands: Array(0)}length: 
    4__proto__: Array(0)id: "5c10307e0ba810224f988e4c"title: "Test 2"
    __proto__: Object
    17:05:57.127 Main.js:17 silo.groups []0: {id: "5c2fdff78b3f6295dce3f63d", 
    title: "Group #1", commands: Array(0)}1: {id: "5c2fdffc8b3f6295dce3f63e", title: "Group #2", commands: Array(0)}
    2: {id: "5c2fdfff8b3f6295dce3f63f", title: "Group #3", commands: Array(0)}
    3: {id: "5c2fe0028b3f6295dce3f640", title: "Group #4", commands: Array(0)}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
    17:05:57.128 Main.js:18 silo.groups[0] undefined
```

From here what I see is that silo is an object and silo.groups is an array.  I can't access any of the elements inside of that array.  even though it shows length of 4 if I do silo.groups.length I get 0 back instead of 4.

I am iterating over the root array with `silos.forEach(silo => {` and expected the same to work for the each silo.groups.

Here is the code that creates the output before.  the first console.log is from just dumping the value of silos when it's loaded into state in the context script.  Before that completes this component would never render.

```
const { silos, user } = value
      if (Object.keys(user).length > 0) {
          const siloList = []
          silos.forEach(silo => {
            console.log("silo",silo)
            console.log("silo.groups",silo.groups)
            console.log("silo.groups[0]",silo.groups[0])
```

I can't figure out what I am missing or what I am getting wrong here.

I can do this by itself if I create a JSON object with this structure I can use these same code to drill into it and get the items back out of each array within each object.  Something is changing when this is done within this app somewhere.  I can't see where though.

--Edit: Adding repo for project --

If it helps anyone here is a github repo of the project as it is right now
https://github.com/jeremyhawkins1/robin.git

Comment: So, do you want to render a React element for each item in the silo?

Comment: Can post your code? We cant do anything without having a look at it

Comment: How much of the code do you need to see?  I will have to look through it, but this project I think I can put onto my personal github

Comment: We don’t need to see all of your code. We need to see a [mcve] *based on* your code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error outside of this situation.  Why I was at first thinking it was a Reactjs issue.  if I just write out a basic script that creates a json object that is an array of objects that contain arrays of objects and then start drilling down into it like I do here it works.  I did just realize that I only copied in the console.log outputs of my code and none of my code itself.  I'll update the question.  Thank you for the link to the documentation examples.

Comment: Hey @JeremyHawkins !! Still there? Can you show me the output of
`for (const k in silo.groups) {console.log(typeof k, k, silo.groups[k])}` ??? I was trying to run your code but I cant Login...
By the way, dont copy & paste the output. Unfold everything and let me see an image of the actual output in the browser console.

Comment: @josué-cortina you can get around the login requirement by creating a user object in the state.  or just remove that check in the main component.  I can update with images. I tried to run the code myself and the backend is timing out.  Thinking the node process running that might of died.  I can check it in the morning when I get in.

Comment: If the server is dead I wont be able to retrieve the silos

Comment: I don't get output from that command. I restarted the server so it should be working now.